# A formula for the 1st and 2nd moments of the inverse matrix gamma distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Given a $p \times p$ positive definite matrix $\boldsymbol \Psi$ and $\alpha>\frac{p-1}{2}$, let us define the inverse matrix gamma distribution $\mathcal{IMG}({\boldsymbol \Psi},\alpha)$ as the probability distribution for a $p \times p$ positive definite random matrix $\mathbf{X}$ with density given by
$$ \rho_{\mathcal{IMG}} (\mathbf{X})= \frac{|{  \boldsymbol{\Psi} }|^{{\alpha }}}{2^{p\alpha }\,\Gamma _{p}(\alpha )}|{\mathbf  {X}}|^{{-\alpha -\frac{p+1}{2}}}\exp\left(-{\frac  {1}{2}}{\rm tr}  (\boldsymbol{\Psi} \mathbf{X}^{-1})\right)\doteq\rho_{\mathcal{IMG},\alpha} (\mathbf{X})$$
where $\Gamma _{n}(\alpha )$ is the multivariate gamma function.
Are the following formulas true?
$$ \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}]=\frac{\boldsymbol \Psi}{2\alpha -p-1}\quad \text{for} \;\alpha > \frac{p+1}{2}$$
$$ {\rm var}[X_{ii}]=\frac{2 {\Psi_{ii}^2}}{(2 \alpha -p-1)^2 (2 \alpha -p-3)} \quad \text{for} \;\alpha > \frac{p+3}{2}$$
For $\nu \doteq 2\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\nu \ge p$, the inverse matrix gamma distribution reduces to the inverse Wishart distribution $\mathcal{IW}({\boldsymbol \Psi},\nu)$. In this special case, the above formulas are true for $ \nu > p+1$ and $ \nu > p+3$, respectively. But, are they true in the general case above?

The moments of the inverse Wishart distribution were computed in a paper by [Dietrich von Rosen (1988)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4616090). A way to essentially rephrase my question is: are the proofs in this paper still valid if we allow the number of degrees of freedom $\nu$ to be a real number?

I guess that a handy way to answer my question is by using an analytic continuation method. How does a rigorous proof look like?

**Context**

I am applying these mathematical objects in the context of research in Data Assimilation for weather forecasting. I am not familiar with them and I am studying things by myself. I have not found any "official" reference answering my question so far.

**My attempt**

Let us try and prove the first formula about the expected value $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}]$, as an example. Let us define the functions $e_S : D \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $e_R : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{p+1\}\to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$ e_S(\nu)=\int_{\mathbf{X}>0} X_{ij}\,\rho_{\mathcal{IMG},\frac{\nu}{2}} (\mathbf{X}) \quad \text{and}\quad e_R(\nu)=\frac{\Psi_{ij}}{\nu-p-1}$$
We know that $e_S(\nu)=e_R(\nu)$ for all $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\nu > p+1$. $e_R$ is holomorphic and I guess it can be extended on the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{p+1\}\cup \infty$ as an holomorphic function.
Let us determine $D \subset\mathbb{C}$ such that the integral in the formula defining $e_S$ is finite. I guess $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}\ |{\rm Re}(z)>p+1 \}$. How to prove that? 
Let us prove that $e_S$ is holomorphic and it can be extended on the extended complex plane $D \cup \infty$ as an holomorphic function. How do we do that? Is [Morena's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) useful? Then, using the identity theorem in complex analysis, we finish our proof saying that $e_S=e_R$ on $D$.

Answer (score 0):

Is the p.d.f. actually IMG? It seems to be inverse Wishart (IW)'s p.d.f.

The most important part of IMG is that IMG is obtained by scaling the scale matrix $\Psi$ of the IW distribution by taking out the variable $\beta$. Namely, you can obtain IMG from IW by replacing $\Psi$ to $\frac{1}{\beta}\Psi$ and multiply $\alpha$ by a constant. So if you have IW distribution and its moments, you can easily see these moments of IMG.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Essentially, the IMG is a generalisation of the IW, in which we allow the number of degrees of freedom to be real instead of just an integer. How can I get the IMG moments from the IW moments? If I multiply $\alpha$ by a constant, then $2\alpha$ will fail to be integer and I will not be able to use the IW moment formulas.

Comment: In my definition of the IMG density, I have set $\beta=2$ without loss of generality.